# NPE Button using Butterknife

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, butterknife

I'm trying to do an exercise from edx.org (Chat Firebase, whole code from https://github.com/ykro/android-chat-firebase) and I cannot understand where does this error comes, it's a NPE but it's getting me off, it crashes when application runs on Genymotion Emulator.

**ERROR**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase/cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase.activities.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)                                                                                     
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
at cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase.activities.LoginActivity.setInputs(LoginActivity.java:114)
at cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase.activities.LoginActivity.disableInputs(LoginActivity.java:57)
at cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase.implementations.login.LoginPresenterImpl.checkForAuthenticateUser(LoginPresenterImpl.java:43)
at cat.edx_manel.exercises.chatfirebase.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

**LOGINACTIVITY**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginView {

@BindView(R.id.user)
EditText inputEmail;
@BindView(R.id.pass)
EditText inputPassword;
@BindView(R.id.signIn)
Button btnSignIn;
@BindView(R.id.signUp)
Button btnSignUp;
@BindView(R.id.progressBar)
ProgressBar progressBar;
@BindView(R.id.layoutMainContainer)
RelativeLayout container;

private LoginPresenter loginPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    loginPresenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(this);
    loginPresenter.onCreate();
    loginPresenter.checkForAuthenticateUser();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    loginPresenter.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void disableInputs() {
    setInputs(false);
}

@Override
public void enableInputs() {
    setInputs(true);
    hideProgress();
}

@Override
public void showProgress() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void hideProgress() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
@OnClick(R.id.signUp)
public void handleSignUp() {
    loginPresenter.registerNewUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
            inputPassword.getText().toString());
}
@Override
@OnClick(R.id.signIn)
public void handleSignIn() {
    loginPresenter.validateLogin(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
            inputPassword.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void navigateToMainScreen() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactListActivity.class));
}

@Override
public void loginError(String error) {
    inputPassword.setText("");
    String msgError = String.format(getString(R.string.login_error_message_signin), error);
    inputPassword.setError(msgError);
}

@Override
public void newUserSuccess() {
    Snackbar.make(container, R.string.login_error_message_signup, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void newUserError(String error) {
    inputPassword.setText("");
    String msgError = String.format(getString(R.string.login_error_message_signup), error);
    inputPassword.setError(msgError);
}

private void setInputs(boolean enabled) {
    btnSignIn.setEnabled(enabled);
    btnSignUp.setEnabled(enabled);
    inputEmail.setEnabled(enabled);
    inputPassword.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}
```

As you can see, button is binded by Butterknife framework, but I don't know what causes it...

Thanks you very much

**UPDATED**

**LAYOUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutMainContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".activities.LoginActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/user"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/pass"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutButtons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@id/layoutButtons"/>
```

**UPDATE 2**

**LOGINVIEW INTERFACE**

```
public interface LoginView {
void enableInputs();
void disableInputs();
void showProgress();
void hideProgress();

void handleSignUp();
void handleSignIn();

void navigateToMainScreen();
void loginError(String error);

void newUserSuccess();
void newUserError(String error);
}
```

Comment: Show us the layout file.

Comment: One last request; post your LoginView interface

Comment: ;) Finally it works! It shows the main layout... but I was following this MOOC exercise and It seems that I didn't do it well (upgrading Firebase & Butterknife version...) Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

First, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754805/how-to-setup-butterknife-plugin-in-android-studio) is one of my answers I shared to setup ButterKnife correctly.

Consider this possible issue:

What are you Overriding here?

```
@Override //this line here
@OnClick(R.id.signUp)
public void handleSignUp() {
   loginPresenter.registerNewUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
        inputPassword.getText().toString());
}

@Override //this line here
@OnClick(R.id.signIn)
public void handleSignIn() {
   loginPresenter.validateLogin(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
        inputPassword.getText().toString());
}
```

Try this instead without the overrides:

```
@OnClick(R.id.signUp)
public void handleSignUp() {
   loginPresenter.registerNewUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
        inputPassword.getText().toString());
}


@OnClick(R.id.signIn)
public void handleSignIn() {
  loginPresenter.validateLogin(inputEmail.getText().toString(),
        inputPassword.getText().toString());
}
```

Then clean your project and run again!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work... I'm using an Interface as you can see in the whole code of my given link, I added some lines on gradle (about butterknife) thanks to your answer, but still looking what happen...

Comment: Interfaces used in a class doesn't actually apply to everything (method) you have. You only need to override the interface methods. Can you post the error logs please? Also, show me your gradle file

Answer (score -1):

I'm referring to the tutorial at [ButterKnife tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/tidying-code-with-android-butterknife/). I think instead of using @BindView it should be @Bind

```
@Bind(R.id.button)
Button button;
@Bind(R.id.textView)
TextView textView;
@Bind(R.id.radioButton)
RadioButton radioButton;
@Bind(R.id.checkBox)
```